# SharePoint Online Rest: Lookup Values visible in list, ID column does not reveal the Ids of the item

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, custom-list, lookup-column, spfx

I have an odd issue today. When looking at a list I can see the lookup field is populated with an item, this is one of a few lookup fields on the list. However when I look at the results of a rest call to the list none of the IDs of the item show up, the collection in the JSON is empty and self closing.

//Lookup field Populated in list
[image: lookup field showing item in list]

//lookup field showing that it has no items in REST
[image: Lookup field showing no REST entry]

//Another lookup field in same list presenting correctly
[image: Another lookup field in same list presenting correctly]

I had resolved this before by deleting and re-creating the column, however the issue returned the next day.

Has anyone ran into this issue before and know how to fix it?

Edit: this was the query used to get all the list data back.
https://<>.sharepoint.com/teams/AIR/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AIR%20Incidents')/items(238)

Edit: Was suggested to use a select and expand to fix issue but did not resolve problem. I have added more info related to this below.

//result of resquested query (modified slightly to show information from list)

https://<>.sharepoint.com/teams/AIR/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AIR%20Incidents')/items(238)?$select=basicSpecificLocation,peoplePerson/ID&$expand=peoplePerson

[image: Lookup not returning ID]

//Column Settings
[image: list column settings]

//Internal Field Name
[image: Internal Field Name]

//List Showing Lookup Exists and has values
[image: List showing lookup exists and has value]

Any further help you can provide will be appriciated.

Comment: Can you post the rest url you are using to fetch the list items?

Comment: Hi, edited question with URL, it was just a simple "get back everything"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

I resolved it myself, it turned out that a lookup field wont return any Id in rest if the lookup field (i.e field/Title) is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below URL:

```
https://<>.sharepoint.com/teams/AIR/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AIR%20Incidents')/items(238)?$select=Title,peoplePerson/ID&$expand=peoplePerson
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh,

Thanks for your help, however this solution did not work for me, I have ammeded my question with notes of how this went.